# Problemas responsives en Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

intento ocultar un span en mi codigo mediante bootstrap.

Solo quiero que se muestre en navegadores y no en dispositivos moviles

```
   <div class="hidden-md-down"><span id="logo-textosp">aenean luctus</span></div>
```

Pero no me funciona

¿alguna idea?

Comment: Pregunto lo obvio primero para descartar. Estás usando bootstrap 4 u otra versión anterior?

Comment: ¿Que version estas usando de bootstrap?, ya que en la 4 cambia completamente la forma de ocultar los elementos

Comment: Podrías mostrar el archivo completo en donde tienes el div de la descripción de tu problema? por favor. Me gustaría descartar que sea un problema de carga del framework como tal en el archivo.

Comment: otra pregunta seria en que movil lo estas mirando? ten en cuenta que bootstrap se basa en el tamaño de la pantalla. Si tienes un movil de resolucion 1920x1080 (que los hay) es posible que te lo muestre (porque para bootstrap no seria un movil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con `class="d-md-none d-block"`que es el equivalente a la clase que quieres utilizar pero la ultima version de bootstrap. Puedes leer más información y los últimos cambios [en la versón 4 beta](https://medium.com/wdstack/upgrade-bootstrap-4-alpha-6-to-beta-ca582f15ee32)

Comment: Si,tenia que utilizar la actualización de bootstrap 4. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo podrías realizar con CSS y query media para diseños responsivos es cierto que todo depende de la resolución como te han comentado, pero básicamente con este @media cuando el ancho de la pantalla llega a 480px (puede ser la resolución que gustes o incluso incluir más con distintas resoluciones) a la clase  `.hidden-md-down` se le garega el estilo `display:none;` para que no lo muestre.
Para ver el resultado prueba el ejemplo en pantalla completa o ampliar.

```css
.hidden-md-down{
height:150px;
width:100%;
display:block;
background-color:blue;
color:#fff;
}

@media (max-width:480px){
.hidden-md-down{ display:none; }
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden-md-down"><span id="logo-textosp">aenean luctus</span></div>
```

Quizá no es la solución más elegante o adecuada pero en ciertos casos funciona.
Saludos.